# Expandable cell won't expand

Tags: ios, swift

I have created two expandable cells but the second one doesn't expand when I tap on it

I googled a lot of ways how to do this but this one seemed the shortest and the simplest one.

```
private var dateCellExpanded: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // For removing the extra empty spaces of TableView below
        self.tableView!.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            if dateCellExpanded {
                dateCellExpanded = false
            } else {
                dateCellExpanded = true
            }
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            if dateCellExpanded {
                return 250
            } else {
                return 40
            }
        }
        return 40
    }
```

I expect to be able to add as many cells as I want and have them expand on tap, but only the first one does.
[Here's what happens](https://i.imgur.com/EmNj5K6.mp4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only working for the first row because you're limiting it to the first row with `if indexPath.row == 0`.

You'll need an array of `Bool` rather than a single `Bool` as you need to track the state for all rows.

Just initialize the array to an array of `false` values with the count of your rows. Set `NUMBER_OF_ROWS` below accordingly.

Then, when selecting a cell, you flip (or `toggle()`) the boolean for that row and ask the table to update.

```
private var isCellExpanded: [Bool] = Array(repeating: false, count: NUMBER_OF_ROWS)

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    isCellExpanded[indexPath.row].toggle()
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if isCellExpanded[indexPath.row] {
        return 250
    } else {
        return 40
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes that you're only using one section. Otherwise you'll have to adjust the data structure `[Bool]` to `[[Bool]]`.

Comment: Side question: can I limit to only one cell expanding at the same time? I.E: if I expand one cell and then expand another, have the first one collapse.

Comment: Use your previous code. But remove the `if` that I mentioned. Instead of storing a single `Bool`, store the index path of the currently expanded row. On select, simply update the index path to the new row.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new at this. How would I do this _Instead of storing a single Bool, store the index path of the currently expanded row. On select, simply update the index path to the new row_?

Comment: `private var expandedIndexPath: IndexPath = nil`; then you set this whenever a row is selected. When returning the height of the row, compare the index path of the row in question to `expandedIndexPath` to determine whether the larger height should be returned.

Comment: _then you set this whenever a row is selected_ set it to what? It's not a boolean so I'm not sure what to set it to. _When returning the height of the row, compare the index path of the row in question to expandedIndexPath to determine whether the larger height should be returned_ you mean like this `if indexPath.row == expandedIndexPath`?

Comment: No :( Because `indexPath.row` is not the same type as `expandedIndexPath`. Also don't know what to put in `didSelectRow`.